# PHP - Does APCu use the same memory pool as defined for opcache?

Tags: php, apcu

According to the docs, APCu is still using the same [configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/apcu.configuration.php) as for APC which includes defining the amount of memory to be used

```
apc.shm_size = 32M
```

But Opcache has it's own [configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.memory-consumption) for memory:

```
opcache.memory_consumption = "64"
```

Does the amount allocated to APCu come out of the total memory_consumption setting for Opcache? Or are they separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are separate, because they are separate modules and so would not want to share memory space.

Since APCu now is only a data-cache (something opCache cannot do), you might not need as much space for APCu either - depending on how much data is being stored.

Comment: Thanks!

We use the [opcache.php](https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status/blob/master/opcache.php) script to monitor opcache usage. I presume the old [apc.php](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu/blob/master/apc.php) script still works for apcu?